# React useContext and useMemo for Global variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Would like to seek guidance from folks if this React implementation makes sense and understand the pitfalls if any. The implementation works but I am unsure if its the correct practice. Please kindly advise.

**Idea** -  Create an AppContext that allows reusability of global states (or even functions) - instead of the conventional useContext + useReducer

**AppContext.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

export const AppContext = React.createContext(null);

export const AppContextProvider = (props) => {

  const [ appState, setAppState ] = React.useState({});
  const  appStateProvider = React.useMemo(() => ({ appState, setAppState }), [ appState, setAppState ]);

  const setAppStateItem = (key, value) => {
    appStateProvider.setAppState(state => { return { ...state, [key]: value} })
    return value;
  }

  const getAppStateItem = (key = '', fallback) => {
    return appState[key] || fallback;
  }

  const deleteAppStateItem = (key = '') => {
    if(key in appState) {
      appStateProvider.setAppState(state => {
         state[key] = undefined;
         return state;
      })
    }
  }

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ appStateProvider, setAppStateItem, getAppStateItem, deleteAppStateItem }}>
      {props.children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

**Create.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppContext } from 'contexts';

const { setAppStateItem } = React.useContext(AppContext);

....
setAppStateItem('count', 5);
....
```

**Consume.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppContext } from 'contexts';

const { getAppStateItem, setAppStateItem } = React.useContext(AppContext);

....
const count = getAppStateItem('count');
....
```

Comment: 1. `state[key] = undefined;` mutates state and will trick React into not detecting the change in state value so your app won't re render. Do `newState={...state}; delete newState[key]; return newState` instead 2. Any change anywhere in your state will cause all components that use the context to re render you can create a `connect` like HOC to prevent that, sample of such a HOC is [here](https://gist.github.com/amsterdamharu/b6d6ed6f6103f15ba70186b13a5fc67a)

Comment: Hey @HMR, thanks for pointing out. For #1, given the state modification is done on the variable passed in by the function, and the "updated" copy is based on what is returned, is it still considered modifying the state directly?

Comment: The state passed to the callback is an object that is your state, mutating this object will mutate the state and `state[key] = undefined;` mutates.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I was under the assumption that Javascript passes by value. Hence, it should be unaffected. However, seems that modifying the member in such manner mutates the original object. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://codeburst.io/global-state-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-87019cc4f2cf) was an approach to create a global state using `useContext` and `useReducer` following a pattern similar to `redux`. You essentially set up a Store with `useReducer` and a `Context.Provider` that you then wrap the rest of your application in. Here was a small implementation I had going:

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import Reducer from './Reducer'


const initialState = {
    openClose: false,
    openOpen: false,
    ticker: "BTCUSDT",
    tickerRows: [],
    positionRows: [],
    prices: {},
    walletRows: []
};

const Store = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, initialState);
    return (
        <Context.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
};

export const ACTIONS = {
    SET_CLOSE_OPEN: 'SET_CLOSE_OPEN',
    SET_OPEN_OPEN: 'SET_OPEN_OPEN',
    SET_TICKER: 'SET_TICKER',
    SET_TICKER_ROWS: 'SET_TICKER_ROWS',
    SET_POSITION_ROWS: 'SET_POSITION_ROWS',
    SET_PRICES: 'SET_PRICES',
    SET_WALLET_ROWS: 'SET_WALLET_ROWS'
}

export const Context = createContext(initialState);
export default Store;
```

Here is the reducer:

```js
import { ACTIONS } from './Store'


const Reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ACTIONS.SET_CLOSE_OPEN:
            return {
                ...state,
                openClose: action.payload
            };
        case ACTIONS.SET_OPEN_OPEN:
            return {
                ...state,
                openOpen: action.payload
            };

...
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default Reducer;
```

I put the Store component in `index.js` so that it's context is available to all of the components in the app.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Store>
      <App />
    </Store>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Then when you want to access and update the state, you just import the actions and context and the `useContext` hook:

```js
import { useContext} from "react";
import { ACTIONS, Context } from './store/Store';
```

and then you just add

```js
const [state, dispatch] = useContext(Context);
```

inside your functional component and you can access the state and use dispatch to update it.

One limitation is that every component that accesses the state with `useContext` re-renders every time anything in the state gets updated, not just the part of the state that the component depends on. One way around this is to use the `useMemo` hook to control when the component re-renders.

```
export default function WalletTable({ priceDecimals }) {

  const classes = useStyles();

  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(Context);

  async function getCurrentRows() {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/wallet");
    const data = await response.json();
    dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.SET_WALLET_ROWS, payload: data });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentRows();
  }, []);

  const MemoizedWalletTable = useMemo(() => {
    return (
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
...
      </TableContainer>
    );
  }, [state.walletRows])

  return MemoizedWalletTable
}
```

Having to memoize everything makes it seem like maybe just using `redux` isn't all that much more complicated and is easier to deal with once set up.